# ¿Cómo puedo generar el id antes de guardar el caso y que se mantenga al persistencia? Netbeans, SQL, Angular

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, jpa

Estoy programando en netbeans un portfolio de proyectos asociado a una persona. La estructura de la entidad es id del proyecto, id de la persona, nombre del proyecto, link al repositorio, imagen y descripción. El problema lo tengo con la imagen.

El id  y la imagen se guarda en firebase con la siguiente estructura: nombreProyecto="nombreProyecto"+id.

Este nombreProyecto es el que uso después para guardar y llamar a la base de datos mySQL y guardar/traer la imagen que corresponde a cada proyecto.

Esta información la cargo desde un formulario creado en HTML con angular.

Este identificador del caso, por mi estrategia de generación en la entidad es IDENTITY y quiero cambiar a uno que me permita generar el identificador del caso antes de guardarlo y que no se reinicie cada vez que ejecuto netbeans.Actualmente me genera esto en firebase como nombreProyecto:

nombreProyecto_undefined

Si luego edito el proyecto asocia una imagen correctamente.

Mi entidad está definida en netbeans así:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class ProjectRepo {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private int persona_id;
private String name;
private String link;
private String img;
private String description;

public ProjectRepo() {
}

public ProjectRepo(int persona_id, String name, String link, String img, String description) {
this.persona_id = persona_id;
this.name = name;
this.link = link;
this.img = img;
this.description = description;
}

public int getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}

public int getPersona_id() {
return persona_id;
}

public void setPersona_id(int persona_id) {
this.persona_id = persona_id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

public String getImg() {
return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
this.img = img;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}


}
```

Comment: Usar una secuencia en base de datos, consumir el siguiente valor y usarlo en las transacciones posteriores que lo necesitan

Comment: Lo resolví de otra forma! igual gracias por responder!

Comment: No sobra compartir tu solución como respuesta, acá abajo en el campo de respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

no lo pude resolver desde el backend, pero lo hice desde el frontend usando la fecha. En la entidad en el componente de nuevo proyecto declaré esto en el id

```
  export class NewProjectRepoComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number = Date.now();
..}
```

luego dentro del método on create  declaré una constante así:

```
const projectRepo = new ProjectRepo(
      this.id,
      this.persona_id,
      this.name,
      this.link,
      this.img = this.imageService.url,
      this.description);
```

Algunas consideraciones con este método. Al ser fecha No es un id único a nivel mundial, pero en un ambiente académico debería ser una solución que ayude